# Remove text that I don't want

Tags: command-line, text-processing

I have a big html file on my desktop that looks like

```
src="http://images.alaablubnan.com/images/Balls/20.jpg"
alt="http://images.alaablubnan.com/images/Balls/20.jpg"/></a></td><td><a
href="http://images.alaablubnan.com/images/Balls/32.jpg"
target="_blank"><img
src="http://images.alaablubnan.com/images/Balls/32.jpg"
alt="http://images.alaablubnan.com/images/Balls/32.jpg"/></a></td><td><a
href="http://images.alaablubnan.com/images/Balls/30.jpg"
target="_blank"><img
src="http://images.alaablubnan.com/images/Balls/30.jpg"
alt="http://images.alaablubnan.com/images/Balls/30.jpg"/></a></td></tr><tr><td><table><tr><td>webpage/url</td><td>http://www.playlebanon.com/webservices/website/lotto/PopUps/HistoryDetail.aspx?t=1405536730503&FromDraw=1&ToDraw=1213&Draw=0</td></tr></table></td><td>2</td><td>complete
lotto results</td><td>complete lotto results</td><td>2</td><td><a
href="http://www.playlebanon.com/webservices/website/lotto/PopUps/HistoryDetail.
```

If possible, I want to:

- get all the .jpg files, remove all the html code (it's  1.jpg, 2.jpg... to 42.jpg)
- I want to remove the .jpg extenstion
- I want each row of numbers to have 7 numbers only, then insert new line

Comment: What row of numbers? Please show us your desired output instead of describing it.

Comment: @terdon this is an example of what I'm aiming to get http://imgur.com/xpPBiMo only difference is i want 7 columns in each row instead of 6, and then new line

Comment: @seth http://askubuntu.com/review/suggested-edits/297813

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is not actually a particularly good job for `sed` but here goes:

```
sed -nr 's#.*/([^"]+).jpg.*#\1#p' file
```

The above will get you a list of numbers, one per line:

```
20
20
32
32
32
30
30
30
```

Now, it is actually possible to get all these on the same line with 7 numbers per line using `sed` but it is really not worth the effort. Just use standard *nix tools instead:

```
$ echo $(sed -nr 's#.*/([^"]+).jpg.*#\1#p' file | tr $'\n' ' ') | fold -sw 21
20 20 32 32 32 30 30 
30
```

Or, if you want to remove duplicates:

```
echo $(sed -nr 's#.*/([^"]+).jpg.*#\1#p' file | sort -u | tr $'\n' ' ')
20 30 32
```

#### Explanation

The `sed` command uses a few tricks:

- `-n`: don't print any lines by default.
- `-r`: enable extended regular expressions, this lets us use `( )` to [capture groups](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) without needing to escape the parentheses and `+` for "one or more".
- `s#from#to#` : while the standard substitution operator in `sed` and other, similar tools, is `s/from/to/`, you can a non standard delimiter so that you can include `/` in the pattern. In this case I am using `#` but you could use something else like `s|from|to|` as well.
- `s#.*/([^"]+).jpg.*#\1#p` : this will match everything from the beginning of the line 
  until a `/` and then captures the longest stretch of non-`"` characters until `.jpg`. This is the filename minus extension. The filename is captured in the parenthesis and the whole line (because of the `.*` on either side) will be replaced with the captured patter (`\1`). The `p` at the end means that it will print the lines where the substitution was successful.

---

Personally though, I would have done all of this with `perl` in the first place:

```
$ perl -e '@k=grep(s/.*\/([^"]+).jpg.*/$1/s,<>); print "@k[0..6]\n@k[7..$#k]\n"' file 
20 20 32 32 32 30 30
30
```

Or, for a larger file:

```
$ perl -e '@k=grep(s/.*\/([^"]+).jpg.*/$1/s,<>); for($i=0;$i<=$#k;$i+=7){print "@k[$i..$i+7]\n"}' file 
20 20 32 32 32 30 30 30
30
```

Or `grep` even:

```
$ echo $(grep -oP '[^/]+(?=.jpg)' file | tr $'\n' ' ' ) | fold -w 21
20 20 32 32 32 30 30 
30
```

Or, stealing @Olli's clever `xargs` idea:

```
$ grep -oP '[^/]+(?=.jpg)' file |  xargs -n7 echo
20 20 32 32 32 30 30
30
```

Comment: Actually, the `fold -w 21` part is not going to work for the OP, since he states that the numbering scheme starts with `1`, not `01`...

Comment: @ClassStacker ah, point. Yes, the `fold` counts characters, not words. `column` _should_ be able to do this dammit but I couldn't get it to play nice. `xargs -n7` is probably the simplest.

Comment: There's also the problem (that I share) that the HTML *probably* isn't going to be split so that there's only one number per line. Convert the input into a single line and most of the `sed` functions fail hard because they replace too greedily. That last `grep` though is the star, just needs a little uniq so you're not pulling in `alt=""` versions of the same number (IMO, but the OP might want duplicates)

Comment: @Oli yeah, the grep is what I'd use. The OP does want the dupes according to their [desired output](http://imgur.com/xpPBiMo). Good point about linebreaks. The perl approach should still work with a `/g` though.

Comment: sed didn't work, it only outputs 31 or 30, maybe it's me, i'm doing something wrong, perl worked but didn't output in the correct sorting, grep worked perfectly

Comment: @Fischer glad it worked. The `sed` works as expected on my system with your example. The perl should also return the same order, nothing it does would affect the order so it's probably a difference between the example file and your actual data. Most likely that things are not nicely organized in lines as @Olli pointed out.

Comment: @terdon There aren't duplicates in each line of 7. They're lottery results, there can't be. They do seem to consistently come out in triplicates (href/src/alt) so perhaps there's a decent way of cutting it down that way. (I say consistently, the first href is missing from the example HTML)

Comment: An old-school way of displaying data with multiple (e.g., seven) entries per line is `pr -7 -l1`.  (`pr -7` would give you typical multi-column output, with 1-56 in column 1, 57-112 in column 2, etc. `-l1` says to output pages that are one line long, so values 1-7 go on the first line, 8-14 on the second, etc.)

Comment: @Scott nice! Though that also adds a lot of whitespace.

Comment: another technique to print 7 words per line: `paste - - - - - - -`

Comment: You can use `-w` to specify the line width for `pr`; e.g., `-w21` if you know that the data (JPEG file names) are at most two characters.

Answer (score 8):

I assume you're trying to scrape some sort of result. In this example there are only three balls and we can extract them by searching for `Balls/<one-or-many-digits>` and grouping (the `\(..\)` construct) around the number and then replacing the whole lot with that group (the `\1` is a reference to the first group).

```
$ sed -n 's/.*Balls\/\([0-9]\+\).*/\1/gp' htmlfile | uniq | xargs -n7 echo
20 32 30
```

`sed` is going through this line by line. I'm asking it to match and replace everything on the line (which is why we cap each end with `.*` — "any amount of anything") with whatever it matches in the group. The `-n` and `/p` are used together to not print unless the line was a match and the `/g` means it'll keep matching until it hits the end of the file.

It's a fairly complicated example if you're new to regular expressions.

I'm passing it through `uniq` because there's a lot of duplication going on there.

And I'm using `| xargs -n7 echo` on the end to group 7 arguments together and pass them all onto `echo`. There aren't 7 balls here so it's only showing 3.

---

It probably slows it down but you can have a slightly more readable expression if you use the `-r` extended syntax for `sed`:

```
sed -nr 's/.*Balls\/([0-9]+).*/\1/gp' htmlfile | ...
```

Does the same thing, just without some of the confusing looking escaping.
Probably ever-so-slightly slower.

Comment: isn't the `g` modifier for making multiple substitutions in the _current pattern space_ (usually the current _line_)? AFAIK it doesn't mean "keep matching until [it hits] the end of the file" - that will happen anyway, unless you explicitly quit (`q` or `Q`).