# Remove all English text and leave Arabic text

Tags: text-processing, grep, perl, csv

This question is a lot like [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/502449/remove-text-that-i-dont-want). I just need a slight modification.

I have a csv file that looks like this

```
y(document).ready(function($) {     $('#wp_mep_2').mediaelementplayer({         m:1                 ,features: ['playpause','current','progress','duration','volume','tracks','fullscreen']         ,audioWidth:250,audioHeight:30  }); });","I'm not"
"100","أستطيع                                                                                                                           00:0000:0000:00  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {   $('#wp_mep_1').mediaelementplayer({         m:1                 ,features: ['playpause','current','progress','duration','volume','tracks','fullscreen']         ,audioWidth:250,audioHeight:30  }); });","I"
"101","كما","As"
"102","شئ","Anything"
"103","منذ","Since"
"104","لذا","So"
"105","واحد","One"
"106","جدا","Very"
"107","يمكنك","You can"
"108","لديك","You have"
"109","الرجل","Man"
"110","يبدو","Seems"
"111","كلا","Both"
"112","لدي","I have"
"113","أوه","Oh"
"114","تفعل","Do"
"115","سيدي","Sir"
```

I want to remove everything except the arabic text, comma separated words that I can work with. Could grep or Perl do it? If grep can do it I will be amazed. I don't know how to detect none English characters, otherwise I would've used the previous question as a reference.

Comment: @KasiyA all the arabic words like `كما`, `سيدي` ideally separated by commas but i don't really care about the looks, i can do that

Comment: So, you need to extract only the arabic words. Right?

Comment: @Perumal93 exactly

Comment: Is it okay if using other commands including grep? I mean using of any other bash commands.

Comment: @Perumal93 sure you can :)

Comment: I just did with this command. `cat file.txt | cut -d ',' -f 2`. Just check it out. If you don't want to get double quotes around the arabic text. You could use this command. `cat file.txt | cut -d ',' -f 2 | cut -d '"' -f 2`.

Comment: I want to make sure about the text which is above those comma-separated words. That text is really included in the csv document or only those comma-separated words? If only the comma-separated words included in the document, above command will definitely work.

Comment: @Perumal93 cut doesn't need cat

Comment: Yep. It doesn't need. I was just using the cat to read file. I haven't used cut command a lot. I have used it only pipe (that is command redirection) cases.

Comment: @Perumal93 for some reason it's not working when i try to put it in a file >> file.csv - but neat solution, and im not able to view it correctly if in terminal although terminator supports many arabic encoding, so i spent the last half hour trying to know if it worked or not :D

Comment: The commands those I have mentioned above will work only when you have comma-separated words alone in the csv document. I tried with the entire text you have given in your question. As I did that, the output was arabic words and some codes like jquery have been displayed. Here is the simple command without `cat` command, `cut -d ',' -f 2 file.txt | cut -d '"' -f 2`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `tr`:

```
tr -s '[\0-\200]' ' ' < file
```

replace all characters from ASCII-code=(0)<sub>10</sub> to ASCII-code=(128)<sub>10</sub> with single space.

`\nnn` is character with octal value `nnn`. (128)<sub>decimal</sub>=(200)<sub>octal</sub>

`[\0-\200]` like alpha class `[A-Z]` it's a character class that includes all [ASCII control characters](http://www.ascii-code.com/).

or use :

```
tr -s '[ -~]' ' ' < file
```

This command is the same as `tr -s '[\40-\176]' ' ' < file` command which replaces all ASCII characters between space and character `~`. See the [ASCII control characters](http://www.ascii-code.com/).

#### Output:

```
 أستطيع كما شئ منذ لذا واحد جدا يمكنك لديك الرجل يبدو كلا لدي أوه تفعل سيدي
```

---

Another way is using that class and `awk` command:

```
awk '{gsub(/[\0-\200]/, "");print}'  file
أستطيع
كما
شئ
منذ
لذا
واحد
جدا
يمكنك
لديك
الرجل
يبدو
كلا
لدي
أوه
تفعل
سيدي
```

You can use the same methods with `grep` command:

```
grep -Po '[^ -~]+' file
grep -Po '[^\0-\200]+' file
grep -Po '[^\x0-\x80]+' file  #used HEX code
```

Comment: your solution works perfectly, may i ask what's the `[\0-\200]`?

Comment: @Fischer sure. see the updated answer.

Comment: Hmm, so `tr` works character-wise, not byte-wise, right? So it wouldn't remove small-valued parts of surrogate pairs of UTF-8?

Comment: @Ruslan I don't think so. From `info tr` *"Currently `tr' fully supports only single-byte characters. Eventually it will support multibyte characters; when it does, the '-C' option will cause it to complement the set of characters, whereas '-c' will cause it to complement the set of values."*. [see this](http://paste.ubuntu.com/9644460/)

Answer (score 4):

Since you asked about perl specifically, it appears to be possible to do it using perl's `\p{ARABIC}` unicode property specifier, although it seems to be necessary to decode the UTF-8 encoding before applying the regex test.

At its simplest, you could just delete non-arabic characters and re-encode:

```
$ perl -MEncode -lpe '$_ = decode("UTF-8",$_); s/\P{ARABIC}+//g; $_ = encode("UTF-8", $_)' yourfile.csv 

أستطيع
كما
شئ
منذ
لذا
واحد
جدا
يمكنك
لديك
الرجل
يبدو
كلا
لدي
أوه
تفعل
سيدي
```

If you want to process the CSV in a bit more of a structured way you could do something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -wl

use strict;
use Encode;

my @F;
my @matches;
my $infile = $ARGV[0];

open FILE, $infile or die $!;

while (<FILE>) {
  @F = split(',');
  push @matches, grep { decode("UTF-8",$_) =~ /\"\p{ARABIC}+\"/ } @F;
}

print join ", ", map {$_ =~ s/\"//g; $_} @matches;
```

Testing again with supplied data as `yourfile.csv`:

```
$ ./print_arabic.pl yourfile.csv
كما, شئ, منذ, لذا, واحد, جدا, يمكنك, لديك, الرجل, يبدو, كلا, لدي, أوه, تفعل, سيدي
```

*[For some reason, the comma and space switch places when the Arabic text is pasted into the browser from my terminal - perhaps because of the right-to-left script property?]*